# Bitbucket under CNTLM proxy

Tags: git, proxy, bitbucket, reverse-proxy, bitbucket-server

I'm using the cntlm proxy and I'm trying to push code to Bitbucket. I have no issue with GitHub, but with Bitbucket I have the following error:

```
(443)
ssh: connect to host altssh.bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreacheable

(22)
ssh: connect to host altssh.bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreacheable
```

I tried to modify the `.ssh/config` file by modifying the `host` and `port` attributes, but it does not work.

Right now, my config file is:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
    Port  443
    #AddressFamily inet
```

I tried all the combinations with the `AddressFamily` attribute.

Comment: What IP do you get for altssh.bitbucket.org?

Comment: I tried 104.192.143.3, which I found in [this thread](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13060/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucketorg-port-443). EDIT: Using `altssh.bitbucket.org` I can see that the address is different from the one that I used: 104.192.143.16. However, if I do `telnet 104.192.143.16 443` I obtain: `Connecting To 104.192.143.16...Could not open connection to the host, on port 44
3: Connect failed`

Comment: 104.192.143.16 is correct for altssh.bitbucket.org, as is 2401:1d80:1010:15f. 104.192.143.3 is one of the addresses for bitbucket.org, where port 443 handles its usual HTTPS traffic, but where port 22 still works for SSH.

Just wanted to be sure things were resolving properly - you'd be surprised how many times these "proxy issues" are actually because of faulty DNS.